# Executing a console application from the command line?

Tags: .net, console

I need to make a basic console application, which will simply upload some documents to my CMS-driven site. However, this will be executed from an automated build. Ideally, it'd be good to execute the console app from the command line. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Anything is possible!  There shouldn't be any reason that an automated system couldn't execute a console app, assuming the console app doesn't require manual input from the console to do its work.

Comment: @Joe: even if it does, the application can be scripted by pre-recording the input you want to feed it into a text file, and redirecting that file into stdin when launching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console applications are executable assemblies. If your automated build process can execute shell commands, then it can launch the console application.  If the application needs input, then command line redirects can be used

Suppose the command takes a list of files, with a newline (basically the enter key) pressed after inputing each file name.  You can then make `inputfile.txt` like so:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

Then, run the command like so:

```
command.exe < inputfile.txt
```

For your automated build process, I am currently assuming you are using Visual Studio.  So, edit your project properties and add the command in either the pre-build or post-build event command line, depending on where you need the functionality.